# Orgmode can't authenticate to WebDAV for mobile-org "push"

Tags: linux, webdav, org-mode

I'm struggling with WebDAV configuration for orgmode MobileOrg sync. (Orgmode documentation suggests using Dropbox for sync, but the last time I checked, that wasn't available in mainland China, where I live for almost all of the year. A local connection has the advantage of being un-blockable by outside authorities.)

Orgmode's documentation on this is on the scanty side.

http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-up-the-staging-area.html

"[2] If you cannot use Dropbox, or if your version of MobileOrg does not support it, you can use a webdav server. For more information, check out the documentation of MobileOrg and also this FAQ entry [next link]."

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#mobileorg_webdav

In this section, three different methods are discussed:

- Mount the webdav service to a file system location, and point orgmode to the mounted location. I tried it. Orgmode creates the files, but within seconds, something in my system moves them to lost+found. No chance of synchronizing to my tablet.
- Use a *tramp* address: `(setq org-mobile-directory "/scpc:user@remote.host:org/webdav/")` -- tried it with `/scpc:my_web_userid@localhost:org/webdav/` and authentication failed. I can authenticate using cadaver as well as Nautilus's "connect to server" (at least, it accepts the password). More below [1].
- Stage the mobileorg files to a regular directory, and use orgmode hooks to drop them into dav. Also failed -- the correct password doesn't authenticate.

[1] But, I just tried again with cadaver -- tried to "put" a file. This said "Forbidden." So, maybe orgmode *is* authenticating, but then failing to write, and reporting this back to the user as a wrong-password situation.

I have:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mobileorg/web/
        <Directory /var/www/mobileorg/web/>
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /webdav /var/www/mobileorg/web

        <Location /webdav>
           DAV On
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "webdav"
           AuthUserFile /var/www/mobileorg/passwd.dav
           Require valid-user
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf is empty.

So, summary:

- Clients other than orgmode: Can authenticate, can't write files into webdav.
- Orgmode: Password is rejected.

It's probably something really simple that I'm missing, but I'm not an expert in Web server configuration.

(There is one other question here about an "Emacs error with MobileOrg push," but that's different from my problem.)

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're getting confused between the different transports.  WebDAV is only used to provide MobileOrg a way of getting to the files.  From the desktop side, if you're using *tramp* via the `scpc` transfer method, then you should be using your **`ssh`** user/password, not whatever WebDAV password you set up.  That might explain why you see that the password keeps getting rejected from the orgmode end.

Note also the caveat in http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#mobileorg_webdav about potentially needing to use `scpx` rather than `scpc` (as it happens, it was me who added that caveat to the docs ;-).  [*tramp* offers several transfer methods](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#External-methods) which vary in subtle ways.  If you are still having problems getting *tramp* to work, read its user manual which explains [how to debug the connection process](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-shell-setup) in more detail.

Finally since you didn't mention that you'd looked at your server logs, if the above doesn't help, I should remind you to do that just in case you didn't already ;-)